# Displaying minted code line numbers from within preview environment

Tags: minted, preview

I'd like to have the line numbers corresponding to code highlighted using the `minted` package displayed in the output of a `preview` environment. Perhaps because the line numbers are set in the margin, they turn out not to be displayed. I've used the `xleftmargin` option provided by the `minted` package, but it's been to no avail. How can this be done?

The document is compiled over `pdfTeX`.

Follows an MWE (the C++ code therein is nonsense, just for the sake of providing some content):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=\parindent,linenos]{cpp}
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned short i;

int main() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    // whatever
  }  
  return 0;  
}
\end{minted}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `\parindent` is zero when you evaluate it.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage[active,pdftex,tightpage,psfixbb]{preview}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
\begin{minted}[xleftmargin=20pt,linenos]{cpp}
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned short i;

int main() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    // whatever
  }  
  return 0;  
}
\end{minted}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You might want to look at the `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass[
  class=memoir,
  varwidth,
  border={20 0 2 2},
]{standalone}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos]{cpp}
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

unsigned short i;

int main() {
  for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    // whatever
  }  
  return 0;  
}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I have myself found a simple workaround which makes sense in the overall context where my post came from. It is not in the strict sense an answer to my post because it involves wrapping the `minted` environment within a `tikzpicture` environment, but it works for me. I'll leave my "answer" unchecked for some time to see if somebody comes up with another not involving such a wrapping.

You can find below the pertinent lines to be added within my original MWE (I have also adjusted the value of the `xleftmargin` key).

```
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node {
  \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{minted}[xleftmargin=1em,linenos]{cpp}
    // Whatever C++ code to be displayed 
  \end{minted}
  \end{minipage}      
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
```

Comment: I can see only part of the numbers to the left.

Comment: It should be a matter of readjusting the `xleftmargin` value.